# DB Scalability for a high load application?

Tags: java, database, scalability

I have seen application to have clustered web server(like 10 to 20 server)  to have scalability where they can distribute the 
load among webservers. But i have always seen all webserver using single DB.

Now consider any ecommerce or railways web application where million users are hitting the application at any point of time.
To scale at webserver side, we can have server clustering but how we can scale DB  ?  As we can not have multiple DB like multiple webserver as one dB will have different state than other one :)

**UPDATE:-**
Is scaling the db not possible in relational DBMS but only in NO SQL DB like mongo db etc ?

Comment: some more tips on how relational and no sql databases scale
http://jamesgolick.com/2010/3/30/what-does-scalable-database-mean.html

Comment: Some RDBMSs do support clustering.  Usually doesn't come cheap though. Example: [Oracle RAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_RAC).

Comment: Clustering is not the only solution to spread the load on databases. You can also use sharding, i.e. spread database contents across multiple servers, with each server holding only part of the database. Iremember seeing a talk about a very large e-commerce vendor doing that with PostgreSQL.

Comment: @JBNizet `You can also use sharding, i.e. spread database contents across multiple servers, with each server holding only part of the database`  But generally all app servers need access to all parts/db objects(I I believe you mean db objects like tables, procedures etc when you say parts). Is it not too tedious to segregate db based on criteria which app server need which db objects ?

Comment: No. What sharding means is that data of a single table is spread across multiple servers. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29. For example, you can imagine that your ecommerce web site will hit database 1 when looking for shoes, database 2 when looking for t-shirts, and database 3 when looking for pants, although shoes, t-shirts and pants are all stored in the same conceptual table "product". Your railway app could look in db1 when looking for departures from Paris, and in db2 when looking for departures from Marseille.

Comment: @JBNizet 
 
 
Here is my understanding :- Basically all shoes, t-shirts and pants will be stored in separate db but still named as product table. Basically its logical separation where we are reducing the data in one specific db logically. Now whosoever is inserting/updating the data knows location of these horizontal shards may be thru shared db or property file. Right  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is two differend kind of scalability on database side. One is read-scalability and other one is write scalability. You can do both with scaling vertically means adding more CPU and RAM to some level. But if you need to scale on very large data more than the limit of a single machine you should use read replicas for need of  read-scalability and sharding for write-scalability.

Sharding is not working like putting some entities(shoes) to one server and others(t-shirts) to another servers. It works like putting some of shoes and some of t-shirts to one machine and doing that for the rest of entities also.

Another solution for high volume data management is using microservices which is more similar to your example. I mean having a service for shoes another service for t-shirts. With microservices you divide your code and data to different projects and to different application and database servers. So you can deal with scalability of different part of your data differently.

Comment: if I store some of the some of shoes and some of t-shirts to one machine and some of shoes and some of t-shirts to another machine, how will java code know which db it has to read from while query for specific shoe ?

Comment: That is the most important question in sharding. You should decide what to use to shard your data. It can be shoe id , it can be brand name whatever suites best for your requirements. But you should choose it wisely so that the data and query loads distributed evenly among the shards.