# Are JPA named queries are eagerly fetched by default?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA with hibernate as implementation

I have below  application code

```
CustomerData customerData = (Customer) getCustomerDataDAO().getObjectByNamedQuery("Customerdata.findByCustomername", queryParameters);
```

which call below method

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> getByNamedQuery(final String queryName) {
        Query queryObject = entityManager.createNamedQuery(queryName);
             return queryObject.getResultList().get(0);
    }
```

Now query fires as soon as queryObject.getResultList() is executed. I was expecting query will be fired when i access some propertt of customerData.
Are JPA named queries are eagerly fetched by default ?

Comment: All queries, named or not, are executed when you call getResultList(). Just as the javadoc says: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29: *Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as an untyped List.*

Comment: BTW, how could you access the first element of a list without having the list in the first place? How could JPA return a populated list without executing a query?

Comment: oh I missed that. I thought query will also be executed when you access the domain object property just like  session methods like get etc. Please post it as answer so that I can accept it

Comment: @JB Nizet Can you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34242610/db-scalability-for-a-high-load-application and share your thoughts if possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All queries, named or not, are executed when you call `getResultList()`. Just as [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList%28%29) says:

> Execute a SELECT query and return the query results as an untyped List.